# append date to iFrame src property with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm passing a disclosure page through an iframe on an html page:

```
<iframe src="../disclosures/Pass_CO_GRN.html" name="disclose" width="790" marginwidth="0" height="400"  marginheight="0" scrolling="Auto" id="disclose" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

I would like to add attach a datetime method to the src attribute to be sure the asset being passed (Pass_CO_GRN.html) does not cache in the client browser. The way I do this with the linked .js file (which I also don't want cached) is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<script language="JavaScript" src="linksHLS4.js?'+(new Date).getTime()+'"><'+'/script>');
```

and this works perfectly. I'm just not sure how to adapt it (if it CAN be adapted) to the iframe tag. anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.write('<iframe src="../disclosures/Pass_CO_GRN.html?'+new Date().getTime()+'" ....></iframe>');
```

Surely.

Comment: easier than I thought. code updated and tested. works like a charm and I am much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jsFiddle.  Is this what you are looking todo?

http://jsfiddle.net/2S5H5/

```
var frame = document.getElementById("myframe");

frame.src = "http://jsfiddle.net/user/signup/?" + new Date().getTime();
```